# Flexslider 100% width creates horizontal scroll-bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/29703851/js/demo/index.html

This is demonstration.

I want to use flexslider with 100% width, but I get that strange additional width and horizontal scroll-bar when mouse cursor is outside of flexslider.

When I go over flexslider, horizontal scroll disappears. Any advices?

I use demo code, no css changes, no js changed. Just deleted all divs around, and left only one div with class flexslider.

Is there a proper way for 100% width?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

problem fixed for me with overflow: hidden; in .flexslider

Comment: This introduces another big problem - missing pager dots.

Answer (score 4):

That will also hide the "pager" dots if you do it that way.
I solved it by adding the overflow:hidden; to the parent container.
I'm working with a responsive layout, so parent is setting width as well.

Comment: I think this is the better answer, works well - the other one does hide the dots.

Comment: Hide the pager dots only if you're showing the dots outside of the container, with negative margins.

Comment: This is the answer. Good catch.